# How to make a single intent match with multiple text lines sent by the user in DialogFlow?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I need help with this issue:

DialogFlow matches the user text block to an intent in order to retrieve an answer. Some users do not type everything in just one block of text, for example:

**"Hello! My name is Ane. How can I order a pizza from here?"**

Instead, they do:

**"Hello!"**

**"My Name is Ane"**

**"How can I order a pizza from here?"**

Each time the user sends a text, the DialogFlow try to match each sentence to an intent. There's some way to make DialogFlow wait a few seconds before match to an intent or put all this lines together or some way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use followup intents in this case.
Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents